# Installed boost-system is not available

Tags: c++, linux, debian

I have a problem with my configure script: If I run ./configure, I get:

```
checking whether the Boost::Filesystem library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_filesystem... yes
checking whether the Boost::System library is available... no
checking whether the Boost::Program_Options library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_program_options... yes
checking whether the Boost::Unit_Test_Framework library is available... no
checking whether the Boost::Regex library is available... yes
checking for exit in -lboost_regex... yes
checking whether the Boost::ASIO library is available... yes
```

But I definitely have installed libboost-system1.55-dev, because Aptitude says so.

If I run make, I get:

```
/usr/bin/ld: network.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.55.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

I am currently running under Debian Jessie.

Here are some parts of my configure.ac:

```
AX_BOOST_BASE([1.55],, [AC_MSG_ERROR([boost 1.55 is needed, but it was not found in your system])])
AX_BOOST_FILESYSTEM
AX_BOOST_SYSTEM
AX_BOOST_PROGRAM_OPTIONS
AX_BOOST_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK
AX_BOOST_REGEX
AX_BOOST_ASIO
AX_BOOST_THREAD

BOOST_LDLIBS="$BOOST_LDFLAGS $BOOST_FILESYSTEM_LIB $BOOST_THREAD_LIBRARY $BOOST_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIB $BOOST_REGEX_LIB $BOOST_SYSTEM"
AC_SUBST(BOOST_LDLIBS)
```

Interestingly everything compiles, if I change the line BOOST_LDLIBS in configure.ac to:

```
BOOST_LDLIBS="$BOOST_LDFLAGS $BOOST_FILESYSTEM_LIB $BOOST_THREAD_LIBRARY $BOOST_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIB $BOOST_REGEX_LIB $BOOST_SYSTEM -lboost_system"
```

But I don't want this, because this is a very dirty hack.

EDIT:
Here is a minimal (non) working example:
configure.ac:

```
AC_INIT([Test],[0.0.1],[],[],[])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall -Werror foreign])   #TODO: remove foreign
AC_PROG_CXX
AC_LANG(C++)
AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX_11([noext],[mandatory])
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])
AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG([-Wall], [CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -Wall"])
AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG([-pedantic], [CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -pedantic"])
AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG([-Wextra], [CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -Wextra"])
AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG([-Werror], [CPPFLAGS="$CPPFLAGS -Werror"])
AX_BOOST_BASE([1.55],, [AC_MSG_ERROR([boost 1.55 is needed, but it was not found in your system])])
AX_BOOST_FILESYSTEM
AX_BOOST_SYSTEM
AX_BOOST_PROGRAM_OPTIONS
AX_BOOST_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK
AX_BOOST_REGEX
AX_BOOST_ASIO
AX_BOOST_THREAD

#BOOST_SYSTEM="-lboost_system"       #TODO: comment this in, to get it working
BOOST_LDLIBS="$BOOST_LDFLAGS $BOOST_FILESYSTEM_LIB $BOOST_THREAD_LIBRARY $BOOST_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIB $BOOST_REGEX_LIB $BOOST_SYSTEM"
AC_SUBST(BOOST_LDLIBS)

AC_OUTPUT([Makefile
           ])
```

Makefile.am:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = mwe

mwe_SOURCES = mwe.cpp
mwe_LDFLAGS = $(BOOST_LDFLAGS)
mwe_LDADD = $(BOOST_LDLIBS) -lpthread

ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4 --install
```

mwe.cpp:

```
#include<boost/asio.hpp>

int main(void) {
}
```

Comment: where you variable $BOOST_SYSTEM is pointing ? Does that directory contains boost_system lib ?

Comment: $BOOST_SYSTEM is an empty string, maybe AX_BOOST_SYSTEM should create this string, but because it thinks that boost-system is not installed in my system, it doesn't set this var.

Comment: can you please try setting this variable and check whether it works or not ?

Comment: Yes, it works, if I set this VAR directly, but this is also a very dirty hack, because it should be set by AX_BOOST_SYSTEM automatically.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal compilable example, so others can test this?

Comment: I have updated the post with mwe of configure.ac, Makefile.am and mwe.cpp.